# @IntDef annotation and return value from other's code that cannot be annotated or how to temporarily disable annotation from affecting the code?

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-support-library, android-lint

I am using [IntDef](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) from [Android Support annotation](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/support-annotations) in my code (but my question is wider in scope so please keep reading :) like this:

```
public class UiLockMode
{
    @IntDef({DEFAULT, NONE, VISIBLE, TRANSPARENT})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface AllowedValues {}

    public static final int DEFAULT     = 0;
    public static final int NONE        = 1;
    public static final int VISIBLE     = 2;
    public static final int TRANSPARENT = 3;
}
```

Next, I got some other methods annotated with it like this:

```
protected void setLockMode(@UiLockMode.AllowedValues int lockMode) {
    ...
```

At that point is all fine and nice but the problem shows up whenever I'd like to pass return value from other methods to `setLockMode()`, like i.e. from Parcelable implementation:

```
private Foo(Parcel in) {
    ...
    setLockMode(in.getInt());
```

In such case my IDE complains that I am only allowed to use `DEFAULT, NONE, VISIBLE, TRANSPARENT` with `setLockMode()`. But `getInt()` is not my method so I cannot annotate its return value and make all this happy. I am also almost sure this is not unique use case but I failed to find the way to either temporarily disable `AllowedValues` annotation from complaining here or to "cast" return value from `getInt()` to make `AllowedValue` not complaining.

So my questions are: is there any way of solving this problem? Maybe I am missing something obvious about annotations but maybe I shall be creating bug report to make Google address this problem instead?

Any input or thought appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can suppress `IntDef` Lint warnings for a method by annotating it with the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
```

You can also disable these warnings for individual statements and whole classes - see the [Android Tools site](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) for further documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1. Yes, I know I can suppress warnings, but I would like not to unless I got no other option, so basically I wonder if here  is any other way of solve my issue.

Comment: I suppose you could try extending Parcel to add the myGetInt method in there.

Comment: Just checked and extending is not a way to go as you will still see complains as annotation makes it expect `int` not a method.

Answer (score 7):

If you only suppress the warning for this single statement by inserting `//noinspection ResourceType` above it, isn't this equivalent to "making it understand the value returned by `getInt()` at this point is correct"?

Alternatively, you could add to UiLockMode a simple method translating from int to @UiLockMode, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
public @UiLockMode.AllowedValues static int lockModeTranslate(int val)
{
    switch(val)
    {
        case 0: return UiLockMode.DEFAULT;
        case 1: return UiLockMode.NONE;
        case 2: return UiLockMode.TRANSPARENT;
        case 3: return UiLockMode.VISIBLE;
    }

    throw new SomethingHorrible;
}
```

Then a call like `setLockMode(UiLockMode.lockModeTranslate(in.getInt()));` will no longer cause a warning.

Comment: Well, suppressing is not equivalent way of saying "this is a correct value". It's often a way of saying "I cannot check that really" or "I do not care it's valid or not" (mostly as result of "I cannot check that really" :). Your code would shut the complaints but it is rather a work around not a solution. If I'd have this thing auto-generated (with i.e. other annotation) then maybe that would be ok, but otherwise suppressing is more clear. Too bad, of course...

Comment: Black magic:

public @UiLockMode.AllowedValues static int lockModeTranslate(int val)
{ 
return val;
}

Comment: @hrules6872 but what if you pass unsupported value?

Comment: Love this solution, since its throwns an SomethingHorribleException instead of unexcpected results